# how to avoid the flickering of a windows for when loading its components/classes.

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm having a problem with regards on flickering of windows form while loading its components.

```
private void frmOrderhdr_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            InitializeInstanceObj();
            InitializedControls();
            InitializedGridControls();
            InitializeFields();
            InitializeComboBoxDataSources();
            ControlSettings();
            PopulateFieldsUpdate();
            SetControlPermission();
            InitializedGrid();
        }
```

as you can see, i have lots of functions inside the Form_Load events. is there any work around to prevent the flickering?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` would work:

```
private void frmOrderhdr_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SuspendLayout();
        InitializeInstanceObj();
        InitializedControls();
        InitializedGridControls();
        InitializeFields();
        InitializeComboBoxDataSources();
        ControlSettings();
        PopulateFieldsUpdate();
        SetControlPermission();
        InitializedGrid();
        ResumeLayout(true);
}
```

If needed, you can also try setting your form's `Visible` to false initially. Then after loading all the stuff, set it to `true` back. This can also be applied to each of component.